# Texture Paint Diffuse and Normal Map Over Existing Diffuse and Normal Map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting

I am texture painting a model. This model already has a texture and a normal map assigned, but I would like to paint another texture and normal map over this existing texture and normal map.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to do:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to paint both the diffuse and normal map of the new texture together over the existing maps, or do I have to do both maps individually, like I am currently doing? A problem with doing each map individually, is that it is difficult to make sure both maps are painted identically.

Comment: We need to see pictures of what you are attempting first.If you intend on a particular mapping for the texture and normal maps independent of the stencil, I woudl hate to tell you the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: @CraigDJones Thank you for your comment and answer. I have re-written the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: You might use the stencil technique described but plug the second set of maps as input into the other shader so that the stencil reveals the second shader with its texture and normal map.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
I used two shaders input to a mix shader (cycles) and used two UV mappings - one is set to the default all faces overlapping for the tiled texture with normal map, and the other is for a smart UV unwrap for painting the stencil.

A normal Map node is for getting the bumps from the normal, and I chose blue for the original shader so it would contrast to see the effect.

Most people imagine that software like Substance Painter is projecting both the diffuse/albedo and the normal at the same time through the brush when it is actually similar to this set up using a stencil to reveal the automatic mapping.